# Pinpointing object on map upon detection

Tags: ros, slam, rtabmap, object-detection

I am doing slam using rtabmap with a realsense d435i. Alongside, I am running a yolov5 node to detect certain objects such chair, tables etc. Now I want to pinpoint the object's position on map upon detection. How can I pull it off?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Niaz Nafi, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: You say you're doing SLAM, but SLAM is simultaneous localization and mapping; the SLAM algorithm should give you your position on the map as you build it. I understand you're using yolo to classify objects, but can you please *edit your question* to clarify how you're implementing the SLAM algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [RTABMap's Wifi Mapping Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/WifiSignalStrengthMappingUserDataUsage).

> To add user data to map, rtabmap node has topics called user_data and user_data_async. The first one is used when parameter subscribe_user_data:=true, and it will be synchronized with other sensor data. It means that the publishing rate of this topic should be high (at least as fast as the images received). The second topic user_data_async is asynchronous. It should be used only when user data is published slower than the detection rate of rtabmap (default 1 Hz).

The `user_data` topic accepts a message of type [`rtabmap_msgs/UserData`](http://docs.ros.org/en/latest/api/rtabmap_msgs/html/msg/UserData.html), which is in OpenCV `CV_8UC1` format. Any data published to this topic will be saved in the map database, so it can be formatted it however you wish. In this case, it can contain positions and type of objects that are detected. Later, when map data is played back, this saved user data can be retrieved through the `rtabmap_msgs/MapData` updates that are published during playback.

For example, this is what they did to retrieve stored wifi signal information:

```cpp
void mapDataCallback(const rtabmap_msgs::MapDataConstPtr & mapDataMsg)
{
   // Convert MapData message in more user friendly objects
   rtabmap::Transform mapToOdom;
   std::map<int, rtabmap::Transform> poses;
   std::multimap<int, rtabmap::Link> links;
   std::map<int, rtabmap::Signature> signatures;

   rtabmap_msgs::mapDataFromROS(*mapDataMsg, poses, links, signatures, mapToOdom);

   // The user data of the latest node added to 
   // map is contained in signatures map. Iterate over 
   // to get the data. Handle the case where we can 
   // receive only latest data, or if all data are published
   for(std::map<int, rtabmap::Signature>::iterator iter=signatures.begin(); iter!=signatures.end(); ++iter)
   {
      int id = iter->first;
      rtabmap::Signature & node = iter->second;

      if(!node.sensorData().userDataCompressed().empty())
      {
         cv::Mat data;
         node.sensorData().uncompressDataConst(0 ,0, 0, &data);

         if(data.type() == CV_64FC1 && data.rows == 1 && data.cols == 2)
         {
            // format [int level, double stamp], see wifi_signal_pub_node.cpp
            int level = data.at<double>(0);
            double stamp = data.at<double>(1);
            wifiLevels.insert(std::make_pair(stamp, level));
         }
         else if(!data.empty())
         {
            ROS_ERROR("Wrong user data format for wifi signal.");
         }
      }
   }

   // "wifiLevels" contains all signal values sorted 
   // by timestamp. We can then find their exact position 
   // on the graph. See referred source code for details...
}
```

You can then use this retrieved information to re-publish it as [`sensor_msgs/PointCloud2`](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud2.html) or Rviz [`visualization_msgs/Marker`](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker) or any other suitable format depending on your choice of UI.

About getting the object's position itself, you can get positions relative to the camera by comparing pixel locations of objects in the RGB image to the registered depth map given by the realsense. Then transform these positions to the global reference frame using transformations that I assume you already have from SLAM.

Comment: @Chuck, apologies, I'll edit my answer avoid adding link-only answers in the future! The wifi signal mapping tutorial explains how you could embed custom sensor information in RTABMap database files, and then later have them show as markers within the map. We have used this feature to mark positions of humans detected during a mapping session.

Comment: @Srijal this is a great edit, thanks!